# What's the proper way to retrieve and display a file off of Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, github, request

I'd like to make an HTTP request to Github and display a text file given a link to the repo.

I had trouble finding out anything about this regarding Github's API but that could just be because it's a slightly niche thing.

See [this website](http://vimcolors.com/), the files are hosted on Github and the way you add a post is by providing a link to the repo.

Comment: Maybe you can use gem `git` . With this gem you can access every git repo and display files inside the repo.

Comment: Will that work with Github or just local repositories, though? Looking into it...

Comment: You can access evry repo you can access via git. This gem is able to act like git and download needed files. You don't need to checkout any repo before using it.

Comment: Oh, I'm just looking to make a request, not to download the file.

Comment: Download a file means you can retrieve it from the repo if you store it into file system or simply display it is up to you. The documentation of this gem is quite good. There you find all your awnsers.